# Switching child components inside v-data-table using buttons(filters)

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component with 2 buttons that I want to use as filters. the child component is called inside a v-data-table.

ScanGrid(parent):

```html
    <template>
      <v-card class="ma-5" v-else>
        <v-flex row xs12 class="pa-3 ml-3">
          <div class="mr-3 mt-2">
            <h3>Regrouper par :</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <v-btn-toggle color="success" v-model="groupBy">
              <v-btn
                text
                value="barCode"
                class="lowerCase"
                v-ripple="{ class: 'success--text' }"
              >
                Code barre
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                text
                value="productDef"
                class="lowerCase"
                v-ripple="{ class: 'success--text' }"
              >
                Définition de produit
              </v-btn>
            </v-btn-toggle>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-layout align-center>
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="items"
              item-key="StorageName"
              show-expand
              single-expand
              :expanded="expanded"
              hide-default-footer
              @click:row="clickedRow"
            >
              <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
                <td :colspan="12">
                  <ScanGridCode :item="item"></ScanGridCode>
                </td>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
                <td :colspan="12">
                  <ScanGridDef :item="item"></ScanGridDef>
                </td>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </template>
```

The children components I want to switch using the buttons are called ScanGridCode and ScanGridDef  inside templates in v-data-table. I tried to find examples of filtering buttons online but couldn't find anything like what I want to do.

I'm using Vue 2.6.10 with Vuetify 2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done already, since you already have the v-btn-toggle set up with v-model="groupBy". All you still need is to add `v-if` to each template, like:

```
<template v-if="groupBy=='barCode'" v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
```